# jQuery tooltip menu does not hide properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to do a homegrown jQuery tooltip menu, as I don't really need all of the functionality (and overhead) of a plugin.

My site features a typical top menu with some items that need dropdown/tooltip submenus.  Markup is as follows:

```
<ul class="topmenu">
<li class="topmenu" id="flink">
<a href="pagewithsubmenu.php" class="topmenu">Link Text For Submenu 1</a>
<div id="fmenu" style="display: none;" class="submenu">
<a href="submenu_link_1.php">Submenu Link 1</a><br>
<a href="submenu_link_2.php">Submenu Link 2</a><br>
<a href="submenu_link_3.php">Submenu Link 3</a><br>
<a href="submenu_link_4.php">Submenu Link 4</a><br>
</div>
</li>
<li class="topmenu"><a href="about.php" class="topmenu">About</a></li>
<li class="topmenu"><a href="contact.php" class="topmenu">Contact Us</a></li>
<li class="topmenu" id="ulink">
<a href="pagewithsubmenudeaux.php" class="topmenu">Link Text For Submenu 2</a>
<div id="umenu" style="display: none;" class="submenu">
<a href="submenu_link_1a.php">Submenu Link 1a</a><br>
<a href="submenu_link_2a.php">Submenu Link 2a</a><br>
<a href="submenu_link_3a.php">Submenu Link 3a</a><br>
<a href="submenu_link_4a.php">Submenu Link 4a</a><br>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

And here is the jQuery I'm using:

```
$("#ulink").hover(function(){
    $('#fmenu').slideUp(300);
    $('#umenu').slideDown(300);
    }, function(){
        var link = $(this);
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            //  $('#umenu').slideUp(300);
        }, 800);
    });

$("#umenu").hover(function(){
    $('#fmenu').slideUp(300);
    $('#umenu').slideDown(300);
    }, function(){
        var link = $(this);
        window.setTimeout(function(){
                $('#umenu').slideUp(300);
        }, 800);
    });

$("#flink").hover(function(){
    $('#umenu').slideUp(300);
    $('#fmenu').slideDown(300);
    }, function(){
        var link = $(this);
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            //  $('#fmenu').slideUp(300);
        }, 800);
    });

$("#fmenu").hover(function(){
    $('#umenu').slideUp(300);
    $('#fmenu').slideDown(300);
    }, function(){
        var link = $(this);
        window.setTimeout(function(){
                $('#fmenu').slideUp(300);
        }, 800);
    });
```

This *almost* gives me what I need.  If I mouse over either of the main links, the correct submenu slides open - and if the other submenu is currently open, it slides closed.  So far, so good.

If I roll the mouse down to a submenu, it stays open for as long as the mouse is over any portion of it.  Once the mouse moves out of the submenu, it slides closed after a short delay.  Perfect.

However, if I simply move the mouse off of a main link WITHOUT either mousing over the other main link *or* the created submenu (say, I move the mouse to the side, then around the submenu), then the subenu will stay open until the end of time (or the browser window is refreshed, whichever comes first).

You note that I have commented out the slideUp() portion related to the parent link LI elements, as they would slide my submenu up once the mouse left the parent link, even if I had moused over the appropriate submenu.  This behavior obviously made the menus unusable, whereas now they are simply slightly annoying.

What stupid obvious solution am I missing?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into all sorts of answers - stop(true, true), playing with classes, etc, I finally settled on a kludgy solution that does at least work.

I have set up a hidden field for each submenu.  On page load, this the value is set to zero.

On mouseover of the submenu, the hidden field is set to a value of 1.  On mouseout of the submenu, the hidden field's value is set to 0.

I have re-enabled the mouseout portions of the hover code on the links themselves, but added an if statement to them.  If the hidden field is set to zero (i.e. the user is not currently moused over the submenu), then the submenu slides up.  If the hidden field is currently set to one (the user is moused over the submenu), then nothing happens.

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" id="fph" value="0"> 
<input type="hidden" id="uph" value="0"> 
<ul class="topmenu">
<li class="topmenu" id="flink">
<a href="pagewithsubmenu.php" class="topmenu">Link Text For Submenu 1</a>
<div id="fmenu" style="display: none;" class="submenu">
<a href="submenu_link_1.php">Submenu Link 1</a><br>
<a href="submenu_link_2.php">Submenu Link 2</a><br>
<a href="submenu_link_3.php">Submenu Link 3</a><br>
<a href="submenu_link_4.php">Submenu Link 4</a><br>
</div>
</li>
<li class="topmenu"><a href="about.php" class="topmenu">About</a></li>
<li class="topmenu"><a href="contact.php" class="topmenu">Contact Us</a></li>
<li class="topmenu" id="ulink">
<a href="pagewithsubmenudeaux.php" class="topmenu">Link Text For Submenu 2</a>
<div id="umenu" style="display: none;" class="submenu">
<a href="submenu_link_1a.php">Submenu Link 1a</a><br>
<a href="submenu_link_2a.php">Submenu Link 2a</a><br>
<a href="submenu_link_3a.php">Submenu Link 3a</a><br>
<a href="submenu_link_4a.php">Submenu Link 4a</a><br>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

And the updated jQuery:

```
$("#ulink").hover(function(){
    $('#fmenu').slideUp(300);
    $('#umenu').slideDown(300);
    }, function(){
        var link = $(this);
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        if($('#uph').val()==0){
            $('#umenu').slideUp(300);
        }
        }, 800);
    });

$("#umenu").hover(function(){
    $('#uph').val(1);
    $('#fmenu').slideUp(300);
    $('#umenu').slideDown(300);
    }, function(){
        var link = $(this);
        window.setTimeout(function(){
        $('#umenu').slideUp(300);
        $('#uph').val(0);
        }, 800);
    });

$("#flink").hover(function(){
    $('#umenu').slideUp(300);
    $('#fmenu').slideDown(300);
    }, function(){
        var link = $(this);
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        if($('#fph').val()==0){
            $('#fmenu').slideUp(300);
        }
        }, 800);
    });

$("#fmenu").hover(function(){
    $('#fph').val(1);
    $('#umenu').slideUp(300);
    $('#fmenu').slideDown(300);
    }, function(){
        var link = $(this);
        window.setTimeout(function(){
        $('#fmenu').slideUp(300);
            $('#fph').val(0);
        }, 800);
    });
```

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Since the submenus are part of the li (you call it "link"), it makes sense to just have the slide up on li out. I'm not seeing any problem with the submenu sliding back up while you are moused over it. Care to elaborate on what browser and version you're seeing this?

```
$("#ulink").hover(function(){
    $('#fmenu').slideUp(300);
    $('#umenu').slideDown(300);
    }, function(){
        var link = $(this);
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            $('#umenu').slideUp(300);
        }, 800);
    });

$("#flink").hover(function(){
    $('#umenu').slideUp(300);
    $('#fmenu').slideDown(300);
}, function(){
    var link = $(this);
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        $('#fmenu').slideUp(300);
    }, 800);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vau9jtos/1/

EDIT:

http://jsfiddle.net/vau9jtos/2/

- absolutely positioned the menu
- static positioned submenu
- submenu container with width of 0 to keep main navbar from expanding

Comment: See, that's what I thought, too.  I'm seeing this in both Firefox 34.0.5 and IE 11 on Windows 7 Pro.  In action url: http://www.homebrewdad.com

Comment: So the reason that the submenu is not part of the li is that you have it absolutely positioned.

Comment: Aha!  Lightbulb on.  That makes sense... and really that's necessary to make it functional, else it pushes everything else down on the page.  Gonna comment those lines back out, now, as it won't work right with them on.  Still looking for a way to make this work... surely it can't really be that hard?

Comment: At this point, I would really like to just get the script working as is.  It seems like this should be very simple.

Comment: Before I go, I would just like to mention that your timeout fails to accomplish anything because as soon as the unhover is triggered, the submenu will disappear regardless of where the mouse is after 800ms.

Comment: Not true.  I can leave the mouse over either the parent link (LI element) or the submenu, and it stays open indefinitely.

Comment: I was referring to something like hovering over the parent and then moving out and back in quickly.

Comment: Hah!  Sure enough.  A new problem to consider.